# Unable to scrape all the listed results with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

https://www.ejendomstorvet.dk/ledigelokaler/koebenhavn-by/detailhandel-butik

I tried to scrape this real estate link. It shows it has 241 results, but I tried several times it can only scrape out 12 results.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

url = "https://www.ejendomstorvet.dk/ledigelokaler/detailhandel-butik"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('div', class_ ="propcontainer")

with open('ejendomstorvet_butik_03-140322.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
thewriter = writer(f)
header = ['title','address_01','address_02','size', 'price','link']
thewriter.writerow(header)

for e in lists:
    title = e.find('div', class_="prop__intro").text.replace('\r\n','')
    address_01 = e.find('div', class_="prop__address").text.replace('\r\n','')
    address_02 = e.find('div', class_="prop__address2").text.replace('\r\n','')
    size = e.find('span', class_="prop__size").text.replace('\r\n','')
    price = e.find('span', class_="prop__price").text.replace('\r\n','')
    link = e.find('a' , href=True)


    info = [title,address_01,address_02,size,price,link]
    thewriter.writerow(info)
```

[Result looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw9uY.jpg)

Comment: What exactly do you want to scrape? Kindly provide some more related info so that we can help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually full data is populated dynamically by JavaScript from api calls json response. Here is a working example how to collect all results.

**Script:**

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
cookies={'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=unma1hbvnwdd53w0iqfh5mfl; search=id=3ee38b0e-551b-4190-a617-cf0dd020d99a&itemtype=OwnUse&url=/ledigelokaler/koebenhavn-by/detailhandel-butik&convertedsearch=0; usercookie=id=f3c5912a-aa72-4a78-bff0-826eaab28072&c=MDMvMTQvMjAyMiAxOTo1NDoxNw==&data=JGYzYzU5MTJhLWFhNzItNGE3OC1iZmYwLTgyNmVhYWIyODA3MgCAo5vl0gXaiAEBJGYzYzU5MTJhLWFhNzItNGE3OC1iZmYwLTgyNmVhYWIyODA3Mglhbm9ueW1vdXMA; settings=usersettings=AAEAAAAAAAZsYXRlc3QABmNsb3NlZAA=; prism_610987956=e5c78891-283e-43ad-a8d9-43db0a7dd452; _clck=1xe2hka|1|ezr|0; CookieInformationConsent=%7B%22website_uuid%22%3A%2281ea14e2-c192-405e-8523-46a926c64030%22%2C%22timestamp%22%3A%222022-03-14T15%3A55%3A15.512Z%22%2C%22consent_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ejendomstorvet.dk%2Fledigelokaler%2Fkoebenhavn-by%2Fdetailhandel-butik%22%2C%22consent_website%22%3A%22Ejendomstorvet.dk%22%2C%22consent_domain%22%3A%22www.ejendomstorvet.dk%22%2C%22user_uid%22%3A%227af36c12-088f-441a-a76a-1a52df8f229a%22%2C%22consents_approved%22%3A%5B%22cookie_cat_necessary%22%2C%22cookie_cat_functional%22%2C%22cookie_cat_statistic%22%2C%22cookie_cat_marketing%22%2C%22cookie_cat_unclassified%22%5D%2C%22consents_denied%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22user_agent%22%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F99.0.4844.51%20Safari%2F537.36%22%7D; _gcl_au=1.1.273465374.1647273316; _gid=GA1.2.924375637.1647273316; _ga_0Q5HR8S1F9=GS1.1.1647273305.1.1.1647273357.18; _ga=GA1.2.1641080384.1647273306; _uetsid=073761a0a3af11ecacdf8b5661088ce4; _uetvid=07379f70a3af11ecbff1db1567aff869; _clsk=nd9336|1647273413426|2|1|d.clarity.ms/collect'}
headers= {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}


api_url = "https://www.ejendomstorvet.dk/search/result?gethighlighted=false&imagewidth=620&imageheight=400"

jsonData=requests.get(api_url, headers=headers,cookies=cookies).json()


data=[]
for page in range(1,17,1):
    #print(page)    
    jsonData['NumberOfPages'] = page
    for item in jsonData['PropertyResultList']:
        title=item['Flashline']
        url=item['RefUrl']
        address=item['Address']
        city=item['City']
        data.append([title,url,address,city])
        #print(title)
cols=['title','url','address','city']

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
print(df)
#df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False) #to store data
```

Output:

```
                                     title  ...             city
0                Nyopført ejendom ved Ny Ellebjerg st.  ...     København SV
1                Nyopført ejendom ved Ny Ellebjerg st.  ...     København SV
2                Nyopført ejendom ved Ny Ellebjerg St.  ...     København SV
3                Nyopført ejendom ved Ny Ellebjerg St.  ...     København SV
4                Nyopført ejendom ved Ny Ellebjerg St.  ...     København SV
..                                                 ...  ...              ...
187                     Strandgade 7, 1401 København K  ...      København K
188  Centralt beliggende erhvervslokale på Frederik...  ...  Frederiksberg C
189                                   Charmerende café  ...      København Ø
190  Velbeliggende mindre butik/café centralt i Øre...  ...      København S
191        Produktionskøkken til leje på Frederiksberg  ...    Frederiksberg

[192 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How could I export them into CSV file with columns: Title(as property name), Address, Size, and Link? I only tried with Beautifulsoup before, so I'm very lost 

Comment: @Mu Yue, I've updated. Now thus way can grab more data whatever you want. Thanks